# How to line up bottom text for child view in VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-view, swiftui-layout

I have the following code which produces the following output.

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            Text("11 / 11 /11 /111/1 111")
                               .font(.system(size: 100.0))
                            Text("data")
                        }
                    )
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            Text("111 / 111")
                               .font(.system(size: 100.0))
                            Text("data 2")
                        }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

How would I get the text `data` to line up with the text `data 2` even though the view (text) above it is a lot bigger, the text `"11 / 11 /11 /111/1 111"`,  and causing the bottom view to be pushed further down? How would I stop that from happening?

I should also mention that I don't want `"11 / 11 /11 /111/1 111"` to be truncated.

EDIT: It's ok if that long text has a smaller font size compared to the text below it. I've tried `minimumScaleFactor` too and the bottom text view is still pushed relative to the top view with long text.

Here's what I'd like to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a variable amount of lines between the two columns, or is it a fixed amount?

Comment: @Yrb it's a variable amount of text not lines

Comment: Can you upload an image of what you want to accomplish? Or do you not care so long as the Bottom 2 lines are even? And does it have to be an overlay on the rectangle, or can should it just look like that?

Comment: @Yrb I updated the post with what I'd like to accomplish

Comment: I don't want to start an answer and have to keep changing it. How about the obvious `Spacer()` between the `Text()` views in the `Stack()`s. You can pad the bottom ones so they are nailed against the bottom of the view.

Comment: @Yrb what do you mean by no answer and start changing it? No answer has been given. Yes, I’ve tried spacers but that doesn’t help since the spacing between the two text views will change with variable text from the above text view. The image provides what I want and doesn’t require an answer to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply put `Spacer()`s in between your `Text()`s in the `VStack()`s.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            
                            Text("11 / 11 /11 /111/1 111")
                               .font(.system(size: 100.0))
                            Spacer() // add Spacer() here
                            Text("data")
                                .padding() // I padded it so this was up a bit from the bottom. Adjust as necessary.
                        }
                    )
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            Text("111 / 111")
                               .font(.system(size: 100.0))
                            Spacer() // add Spacer() here
                            Text("data 2")
                                .padding() // I padded it so this was up a bit from the bottom. Adjust as necessary.
                        }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code leaves you with this:

[image]